# why doesn't this mod_rewrite work?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2, debian

I am facing an issue which I cant resolve.

this is my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w\d~%.:_\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+) /news?id=$1
RewriteRule ^contact/([0-9]+) /contact?do=$1
RewriteRule ^account/([a-zA-Z]+) /account?action=$1
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z]+) /admin?action=$1
```

Everything works beside the admin and account rules
when I go the one if the working once, Then I get to the requested page
i.e
www.domain.com/page
or
www.domain.com/news/3

All working rules are ending in numbers, like the news rules,
But admin and account rule doesnt end in a number, but in a string, like
www.domain.com/account/settings

which doesnt work.

Anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

([0-9]+) only matches numbers. If you want to match Strings, use either (.+) to match every character or some other character group ([a-zA-Z]+ for example).

To learn on how to use regular expressions, I recommend:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Ahhh, thank you very much, I must be tried since I didn't notice that, hehe :)

Comment: Mind to accept the answer if it did solve your problem? That way people see that the issue is solved.

Comment: Did that now :), thanks for notice me, still new to this system, I would also like to give you a +1, but I can't yet :)